# local storage variables are reinitialized when i quit the application

Tags: react-native, local-storage

what i want to do is to show a dialog box when i open the app,but i want to condition this display to a variable stored in my app local storage.
this variable get initialized when i click on a button.
i'll explain my case:

when i click on my button i do call this function which store data in my local storage as follow:

```
  storeDate = async () => {
    try{
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@key',true)
        }catch(e){
            alert("an error has occured when s")
        }
    }
```

and in my componentDidMount, according to my @key variable i do display my dialog box or not, here is my code for doing that:

```
  componentDidMount(){

       // this alert is used to check my @key variable value
       alert(this.getData());

       if (this.getData() == true){
           this.setState({
            dialogVisible2:true
           });
       }
   }
```

here is my getData function:

```
   getData = async () =>{
    try{
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@key')
        if (value !== null){

            return  value;
        }
        return "undefined";
    }catch(e){
        alert("an error has occured when retrieving data")
    }
}
```

when i close the app and re-open it the alert returns me the following   [ object Objecct].

can anyone tell me where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `componentDidMount` function runs first before data is obtained from `Asyncstorage`, so the value is imported.

So you can configure `componentDidMount` as a asynchronous system.

```js
async componentDidMount(){

      getdata  = await this.getData()
       alert(getdata);

       if (getdata === true){
           this.setState({
            dialogVisible2:true
           });
       }
   }
```

Comment: Not sure if you can make `componentDidMount()` as async.

Comment: All functions can be changed asynchronously.